# how to make nested HashMap in java

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

i'm trying to put an anonymous hashmap into another hashmap:-

```
Map<String, Object> requestBody=new HashMap<String, Object>();
requestBody.put("UPSSecurity", new HashMap<String, Object>().put("username","rohan"));
System.out.println(requestBody);
```

Output is:-

```
{UPSSecurity=null}
```

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242665/java-how-to-adress-a-hashtable-in-a-hashtable/29242857#29242857

Comment: You are calling ```put```, which returns the previous element at that key. Since the map was empty, that is ```null```.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use this way to define your Nested Hashmap.

```java
Map<String, Object> requestBody=new HashMap<String, Object>();
Map<String,Object> userdetails=new HashMap<String, Object>();
userdetails.put("username","rohan");
requestBody.put("UPSSecurity",userdetails );
System.out.println(requestBody);
```

Output:

`{UPSSecurity={username=rohan}}`

Comment: so if there are 10 nested hashmaps then i have to create 10 local hashmaps

Comment: how to extract the data of UPSSecurity

Comment: How to get 10 nested hashmap data

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it this way.

```
Map<String, Object> requestBody=new HashMap<String, Object>();
requestBody.put("UPSSecurity", new HashMap<String, Object>());
requestBody.get("UPSSecurity").put("username","rohan");
```